# How can I capitalize the first letter of item-text for a combobox?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a bunch of objects that I use as items in a Vuetify combobox:

```
*availableCities*:
{
    created_at:null,
    id:1,
    name:"sandton",
    province_id:1,
    updated_at:null,
},
{
    created_at:null,
    name:"johannesburg"
    ...
}
```

I then use these as selectables in a v-combobox:

```
<v-combobox
    :items="availableCities"
    item-text="name"
    label="City"
    ...
></v-combobox>
```

I want to capitalize the name of each city when being displayed in the combobox for selection, without changing its value in the object. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the property `item-text` can be a [string, variable or a function](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-combobox/#item-text)

So for your purpose, you can replace your item-text with

`:item-text="item=>item.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.name.slice(1)"`

or create a method

```
:item-text="text"

methods:{
   text(item){ 
     return item.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.name.slice(1) 
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [item slot](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-combobox/#item) :

```
<v-combobox
    :items="availableCities"
    item-text="name"
    label="City"
    ...
>
<template v-slot:item="{item}">
  {{item.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.name.slice(1)}}
</template>
</v-combobox>
```